# How many permutation are there of n distinct elements if two specific elements will not appear either in the 1st place or in the last place?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

Let the elements be $a_1$,$a_2$,...,$a_n$. Let the two specific letters be $a_1$ and $a_2$. What does the question mean when it says that TWO letters do not appear either in the first place or in the last place? Does it mean that neither can they occupy the first place nor the last place? Or does it mean that if they do not occupy the first place, they are free to occupy all other places and if they do not occupy the last place, they are free to occupy all other places?

Comment: I would read it as saying "there are two indices, $i\neq j$ such that neither $a_i$ nor $a_j$ appears first or last."  Imagine you are seating $n$ people in a row.  How many ways can you do this if neither Alice nor Bob wants to sit on an end?

Comment: That means Alice and Bob can sit in any of the other n-2 positions. If one of them sits down, s/he can do it in n-2 ways and the other can do it in n-1 ways. As the second depends on the first, I multiply the ways. There are n-2 remaining positions in which I can put n-2 distinct elements. So, I can do this in (n-2)! ways. This depends on the previous. So, the total number of ways is (n-2)!*(n-2)(n-1) much like what @manthanein said.

Comment: Thank you @lulu. I think the real problem is my lack of understanding in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpreted the question correctly then the method is as follows.

First permute the two specific elements at the ends in $2!$ ways and the rest in $(n-2)!$ways . 
Now we need to subtract this case from all the permutations that can be done using all $n$ elements which is $n! $

Hence the answer to the question can be given as $$n! -(n-2)!2!=(n-2)!(n-2)(n+1)$$